# Debug Ruby/Rails startup issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Staring at an error like so:

```
Exiting
/Users/llcool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:111:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
```

Where's my best starting point to figuring out what the issue is here? I've tried gem pristine and bundle install but the issue still persists. Some version conflict somewhere I assume.

**UPDATE 1**

After running some of the commands suggested I'm now getting this error :(

```
/Users/llcool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bcrypt-3.1.16/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/llcool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bcrypt-3.1.16/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle (LoadError)
```

**UPDATE 2**

Still having issues getting this app to load...

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.7.1.beta3, debase 0.2.5.beta2, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:55189
Uncaught exception: incompatible library version - /Users/llcool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bcrypt-3.1.16/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle
```

I've tried update, pristine, uninstall, reinstall, etc all with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

When I have seen this before I delete the Gemfile.lock file, update gem and bundler:

```
gem update --system
```

And

```
bundle update --bundler
```

Then run `bundle install` again and see if that clears it up.

Comment: slightly different error now - updating OP